# How to make a SOAP request in python through TLS

Tags: python, ssl, soap

I am getting the following error when trying to make a request through TLS

```
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 111, in post
return request('post', url, data=data, json=json, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py2.7.egg\requests\api.py", line 57, in request
return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 476, in request
resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py2.7.egg\requests\sessions.py", line 586, in send
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\requests-2.10.0-py2.7.egg\requests\adapters.py", line 491, in send
raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    requests.exceptions.SSLError: [SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:590)
```

So maybe the request I am making is also wrong?
This is what my request looks like.

```
 import json
 import requests
 from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
 from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager 
 import ssl

 class myAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
""""Transport adapter" that allows us to use SSLv3."""
def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False):
    self.poolmanager = PoolManager(num_pools=connections,     maxsize=maxsize,block=block, ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)

 s = requests.Session()
 jsondata = json.dumps({
 "wsRequestHeaderV2": {
},
 "requestData": {})
  headers = {'content-type': 'application/json'}
  payload = {'json_payload':jsondata}
  r = s.post('HTTP://URL', data=payload,headers=headers,verify='LALA.PEM')

  print r
```

Comment: If I was a bettin' man, I'd say that anything that smacks of "alert handshake" is probably *trying,* perhaps unsuccessfully, to "pop a dialog box." Are you *really sure* that the second cert doesn't require a password?  ### Generally speaking, I suggest that "password-protected certs" are merely a nuisance for *scripts.* (They're really aimed at road-warriors who tend to lose their laptops in airport-security ...) You should be able to properly protect the cert from disclosure on the computer upon which it is being used.

Comment: actually i realized it is because I need it to be TLS protocol. but i still can't get it to work